# How can I download code for game levels in iOS?

Tags: ios, xml

guys!
I want to build a game for iOS, and I need to download levels for it. Levels should allow me to organize conditional statements, simple object discription. I know that downloading any code in iOS is prohibited, so I can't use Lua or smth. But how do other applications solve this problem?

Comment: You could code them into the game, and just download a key to enable them. If you give us more details of the levels, I could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: We need to give an opportunity to the comunity to create their own levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use XML? You can have flags like: `<conditionalA>true</conditionalA>` to handle your conditionals and descriptions (textual?) can again be wrapped inside tags:

`<descriptionA>description</description>`.

If you meant description in terms of position of objects, you can do things such as

`<position>100, 100</position>`

Have a look at [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you do decide to do something like this.

Comment: We need to have if/then statements so that we could organize conditions.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have those conditions set in the Data files you're loading.It's all about design.

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of file that describes how the level looks. Lets say you have a game where the user has to walk through a maze. You could have a text file which shows the map:

```
######## #
#        #
# ########
#        #
######## #
#        #
# ########
```

Well, this is really simple. The `#` characters are walls ...

You could then already implement all the logic in the code that you ship with your application and just download the files describing your levels. So you are not downloading any codes, just files that you have to parse with the code you already shipped

Comment: That was just an example ;) You could also have some sort of logic described in a textfile and evaluate that ... Just wanted to make the point clear that you should implement all the code in your app and then download little files where you describe what you want your logic to do

Answer (score 0):

Any code already should be in your app. Downloaded level could only contain data which app could decode and behave appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Expansion packs, Mods, etc. are all data.

Design your application to read XML / Text / Some sort of serialized data to create level's, characters, events etc.

Then when you want to release something new, You package it up as that data (XML, text, serialized etc.).

You don't need to have code, as your application should already know how to interpret that data.